# Unity launcher: how can I make it show one icon per window?

Tags: unity

I have a lot of chrome windows open on my machine (and multiple chrome profiles, even), but they all get merged down into one icon in the unity launcher.

Is there a way to make them each show up as one icon?   Or at least separate by chrome profile?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the "simpliest" way is to use an alternative desktop environment rather than Unity.
Look at Xfce or KDE.